# Flask-Sqlalchemy: Table with 3 primary keys that are also foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy, composite-primary-key

I am trying to translate a table from pure SQL to Flask-Sqlalchemy, but the documentation available is not clear about how to do this specific scenario - Primary keys that are also foreign keys.

The SQL to build the table is the following and it works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ws`.`Perfil_Plano_Transacao` (
    `pptr_perf_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `pptr_tran_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `pptr_plan_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `pptr_dt_incluscao` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pptr_dt_atualizacao` TIMESTAMP NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pptr_perf_id`, `pptr_tran_id`, `pptr_plan_id`),
INDEX `fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1_idx` (`pptr_tran_id` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1_idx` (`pptr_plan_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Perfil1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pptr_perf_id`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Perfil` (`perf_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pptr_tran_id`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Transacao` (`tran_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pptr_plan_id`)
    REFERENCES `ws`.`Plano` (`plan_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And the Python code I've come until here is:

```
class PerfilPlanoTransacaoModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'perfil_plano_transacao'

    pptr_perf_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    pptr_plan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    pptr_tran_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    pptr_dt_inclusao = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    pptr_dt_atualizacao = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['pptr_perf_id', 'pptr_plan_id', 'pptr_tran_id'],
            ['perfil.perf_id', 'plano.plan_id', 'transacao.tran_id'],
            ['fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Perfil1', 'fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1', 'fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1']
        ),
    )
```

I would like to know if I am going toward the right way. I dind't find, for example, how to declare the `name` of the foreign key constraint and how to set the `INDEX`. Is there a more `Flaks-Sqlalchemy` way to do all this?

Comment: why would you have more than a single primary_key? and why would it be possible? I think you want a foreingKey and a relationship field

Comment: @NotSoShabby Because in this case, the primary key is composed by the primary keys of other 3 tables (Role, Plan and Transaction). It is a very common and known use case. In this case, this table is used to give me the transactions a profile can make under a specific plan. Ex: If you pay for plan type A and you are the vip role, you can make transactions X and Y, but if you are the regular role, you can just use transaction Y.

Comment: isnt the other foreing keys belong to the other tables? im pretty sure you can only have one primary key per table. what error are you getting?

Comment: @NotSoShabby Yes, they belong to other tables as expected for a foreign key :-). On SQL it is very common to have a composed primary key and the SQL presented works fine. The point is I can't find examples of this specific presented scenario in Flask-Sqlalchemy. I didn't get any errors yet, because I din't tried to run the code. I am trying to find better examples to make sure it will work as expected and not just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to declare the `name` of the foreign key constraint**

Adding multiple foreign key constraints can be done by having multiple `ForeignKeyConstraint`s in your `__table_args__`. For example:

```
__table_args__ = (
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['pptr_perf_id'], ['perfil.perf_id'], name='fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Perfil1'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['pptr_plan_id'], ['plano.plan_id'], name='fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['pptr_tran_id'], ['transacao.tran_id'], name='fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1'),
)
```

Here you see that your define your local column, then the column in the original table and give it a name. The reason the first two parameters are arrays are to allow for composite foreign keys.

Making this change to your code should evaluate to the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE perfil_plano_transacao (
        pptr_perf_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        pptr_plan_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        pptr_tran_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        pptr_dt_inclusao DATETIME NOT NULL,
        pptr_dt_atualizacao DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY (pptr_perf_id, pptr_plan_id, pptr_tran_id),
        CONSTRAINT "fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Perfil1" FOREIGN KEY(pptr_perf_id) REFERENCES perfil (perf_id),
        CONSTRAINT "fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1" FOREIGN KEY(pptr_plan_id) REFERENCES plano (plan_id),
        CONSTRAINT "fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1" FOREIGN KEY(pptr_tran_id) REFERENCES transacao (tran_id)
)
```

**How to set the `INDEX`**

The simple way of adding an index is setting it on the column declaration:

```
pptr_perf_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
pptr_plan_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, index=True)
pptr_tran_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, index=True)
```

Which would lead to the following two queries:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_perfil_plano_transacao_pptr_plan_id ON perfil_plano_transacao (pptr_plan_id)
CREATE INDEX ix_perfil_plano_transacao_pptr_tran_id ON perfil_plano_transacao (pptr_tran_id)
```

Or you can add it separately after the table declaration:

```
from sqlalchemy import Index
Index('fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1_idx', PerfilPlanoTransacaoModel.pptr_tran_id.asc())
Index('fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1_idx', PerfilPlanoTransacaoModel.pptr_plan_id.asc())
```

Which would lead to the following two queries:

```
CREATE INDEX "fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Transacao1_idx" ON perfil_plano_transacao (pptr_tran_id ASC)
CREATE INDEX "fk_Perfil_Plano_Transacao_Plano1_idx" ON perfil_plano_transacao (pptr_plan_id ASC)
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @Halvor is right, but I'll just add that you have a composite primary key but not a composite foreign key, you have three single column foreign keys pointing to different tables which means you can declare the foreign key in your column definition too:

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

class PerfilPlanoTransacaoModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'perfil_plano_transacao'

    pptr_perf_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        ForeignKey('perfil.perf_id'),
        primary_key=True, 
        autoincrement=False,
    )
    pptr_plan_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        ForeignKey('plano.plan_id'),
        primary_key=True, 
        autoincrement=False,
    )
    pptr_tran_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        ForeignKey('transacao.tran_id'),
        primary_key=True, 
        autoincrement=False,
    )
    pptr_dt_inclusao = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    pptr_dt_atualizacao = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
```

Using `ForeignKeyConstraint` is a little bit more verbose than using `ForeignKey` and the `ForeignKey` objects we create in your column definitions in this example are eventually converted to `ForeignKeyConstraint` objects anyway, its just easier to use the `ForeignKey` object when you are dealing with single column keys. The `ForeignKeyConstraint` object defined in `__table_args__` is usually only used directly when you need to create a composite foreign key, for example if you had another table that wanted to reference `perfil_plano_transacao`, it would need to be a composite foreign key and you'd have to define it as you have done above.

I'll defer to @Halvor's answer for the rest of your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will definitely use a mix of both (yours and @Halvor), because your contribution shows a high level usage of the library, but the accepted answer gave me exactly the answers I was looking for.